# Additional loader for createRequire on React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babel-loader

I've installed some module on my react application

these are the error I got. Please if you guys have some solution.

`./node_modules/hafas-client/p/db/index.js 4:36
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:36)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | // https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions
  | import { createRequire } from 'module';

> const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
> | import trim from 'lodash/trim.js';
> | import uniqBy from 'lodash/uniqBy.js';
> `

I've try to upgrade react-script or find some loaders which can be solve this issue but no success